# Autocompletar com jQuery e Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-ui, django-1.8

Olá, fiz uma busca no site, mas não encontrei, se alguém conhece um link que já trate deste assunto, favor postar.

Seguinte, fiz um autocomplete em um form do Django com jQuery e jQueryUI, nesse form tenho um foreignkey e usei um widget text input para poder fazer o autocomplete que inclusive está funcionando, o problema está quando tento persistir esse form, veja a saída com o erro.

ValueError at /consultorio/agenda/
Cannot assign "'Francisco André Filho'": "Agenda.paciente" must be a "Paciente" instance.

## views.py

```
def add_agenda(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_agenda = AgendaForm(request.POST)
    if form_agenda.is_valid():
        form_agenda.save()
        return redirect(reverse('paciente:listaagenda'))
    else:
        print(form_agenda.errors)
else:
    form_agenda = AgendaForm()
return render(request, 'paciente/add_agenda.html', {'form_agenda': form_agenda})
```

## view ajax

```
def get_pacientes(request):
if request.GET:
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    pacientes = Paciente.objects.filter(nome__icontains = q)[:20]
    results = []
    for paciente in pacientes:
        paciente_json = {}
        # paciente_json['id'] = paciente.id
        # paciente_json['label'] = paciente.nome
        paciente_json['value'] = paciente.nome
        results.append(paciente_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
else:
    data = 'fail'
mimetype = 'application/json'
return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

## forms.py

```
class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
paciente = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
class Meta:
    model = Agenda
    fields = ('paciente', 'medico', 'data_consulta', 'horario', 'observacoes')
```

A questão é basicamente informar ao campo paciente de agenda o id do paciente, mas não consigo fazer isso, já tentei várias coisas.

De já agradeço a disposição de todos. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece porque você está recebendo um `CharField` em vez de receber uma instância de Paciente.

Remova o `paciente` do seu forms.py:

```
class AgendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # linha removida
    class Meta:
        model = Agenda
        fields = ('paciente', 'medico', 'data_consulta', 'horario', 'observacoes')
```

E insira manualmente no seu template o campo `paciente`.

template.html:

```
<input type='text' id='id_paciente' name='paciente' />
```

Não sei como funciona o autocomplete do jQuery, mas isso resolve o problema que está sendo gerado.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, fiz algumas mudanças no forms.py e o campo paciente eu usei um modelchoicefield, o erro anterior sumiu, agora eu tenho outro erro: "Faça uam escolha válida...

PS: vou testar sua dica ainda.